# How do you get pthreads to compile with Phalanger?

Tags: php, multithreading, compilation, pthreads, phalanger

So i have pthreads working with PHP on windows, but how can i compile and run my pthreads implementations with phalanger 3.0? 
At the moment, it builds with 0 errors / 0 warnings, but then when i run it it says

```
CompileError: The class 'ThreadTest' is incomplete - its base class or interface is unknown in C:\phptests\thread.php on line 10, column 1.
```

I see in the Phalanger install dir it has the php extensions .dll's; and the php_pthreads zip i downloaded it has .pdb intermediate files for the pthreads .dll's, so is there a way to get Phalanger to compile and run pthreads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phalanger does not have a support for pthreads.

You can use .NET alternatives via `clr_create_thread(callback [, parameters])` function or sb. has to implement missing support for pthreads in C#.

`clr_create_thread` is bit misleading name though, as it doesn't really create a thread. Instead it takes your callback and schedules it for execution on a [ThreadPool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool(v=vs.110).aspx). Threads on a thread pool are somewhat special as they do not end when your callback ends. Instead they are reused for later requests (like if you call `clr_create_thread` again the callback execution *may* end up on the thread you used previously). As such, there's little sense in `Join`ing `ThreadPool` threads, as they do not end voluntarily. However, you may use other .net synchronization mechanisms if you want to wait for your callback(s) to finish (`AutoResetEvent` and `WaitHandle::WaitAll` are the important parts):

```php
use System\Threading;
class ThreadTest
{
    public static function main()
    {
        (new self)->run();
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $that = $this;

        $finished = [];

        for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
            $finished[$i] = new Threading\AutoResetEvent(false);
            clr_create_thread(function() use ($that, $finished, $i) {
                $that->inathread();
                $finished[$i]->Set();
            });
        }

        Threading\WaitHandle::WaitAll($finished);
        echo "Main ended\n";
    }

    public function inathread()
    {
        $limit = rand(0, 15);
        $threadId = Threading\Thread::$CurrentThread->ManagedThreadId->ToString();
        echo "\n thread $threadId limit: " . $limit . " \n";
        for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++) {
            echo "\n thread " . $threadId . " executing \n";
            Threading\Thread::Sleep(1000);
        }
        echo "\n thread $threadId ended \n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, how do i join/detach threads created like this? i cant find any documentation